# Azure App Store

Tags: api, rest, azure

We are looking to go through the certification process and add an app to the **Azure App Store**. I have a few questions that you hopefully can answer that will increase my understanding how to implement a Resource Provider API.

1. BIG Picture – Can you tell me how the process of purchasing an app works?  Do you already have to have a resource setup or is that part of the setup process?
2. BIG Picture – Where  does the RP service (REST APIs) go in the system?  Does the customer purchase a resource and/or server VM first and the RP Service is already installed on that resource?  How is the RP service installed? Does the Store make the API requests against the provisioned resource or a different server that hosts the RP service?
3. If the RP server responding to the REST APIs is installed on the server where the application is installed, what happens if the customer shuts off the RP server and it can’t respond to the disable REST request?  How is the app stopped or disabled?

Answer (score 1):

Resource Provider (RP) Service is hosted by you, runs 24x7 and is capable of on-boarding customers by responding to calls from Azure Store.  It is independent of your application.

Where your actual application is installed is irrelevant.  RP Service is only there to respond to Azure Store in a multi-tenant sort-of fashion - Azure Store on behalf of many customers will issue calls to your RP service.  Your RP service needs to provision/deprovision whatever Resources that these customers are subscribing/unsubscribing to.

HTH